# how do I prevent my variables going on forever?

Tags: java, variables, loops, while-loop

Dr.Java won't run my program because my variables are going on forever and I'm not sure how to prevent that from happening. If you could tell me how to fix that, it'd be great. I'm a beginner so this is all foreign to me.

here's the code for the class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
class PaintablePicture extends Picture {
    public PaintablePicture(String fileName) {
        super(fileName);
    }

    public void purpleSplotch(int x, int y) {
        int x1 = 0;
        int y1 = 1;
        while (x1 < x * 2)
            while (y1 < y * 3)

            {
                Color purple = new Color(175, 0, 175);
                Pixel pixRef;
                pixRef = this.getPixel(x, y);
                pixRef.setColor(purple);

            }
        return;

    }
}
```

and then this is the method I'm running it in(ignore all the artistic turtle stuff that's for the other class and everything worked fine for that until I started the paintable picture.

```
public class GraffitiApp
{
  public static void main(String[] a)
{

FileChooser.pickMediaPath();
PaintablePicture pRef;
pRef = new PaintablePicture(FileChooser.pickAFile());
pRef.purpleSplotch(14,14); 
pRef.purpleSplotch(17,20);

ArtisticTurtle tRef = new ArtisticTurtle(pRef);
tRef.pentagon(20);
tRef.spiral(50);
tRef.penUp();
tRef.forward(-50);
tRef.turn(90);
tRef.penDown();
tRef.letterK(50);
tRef.penUp();
tRef.turn(-130);
tRef.forward(100);
tRef.turn(90);
tRef.forward(140);
tRef.penDown();
tRef.letterK(30);
tRef.penUp();
tRef.moveTo(486, 60);
tRef.penDown();
tRef.star(30);
tRef.penUp();
tRef.moveTo(159,122);
tRef.turn(30);
tRef.penDown();
tRef.star(60);
tRef.penUp();
tRef.moveTo(330,103);
tRef.turn(-67);
tRef.penDown();
tRef.pentagon(40);
tRef.penUp();
tRef.moveTo(471,158);
tRef.penDown();
tRef.spiral(35);

pRef.explore();
```

}
}

Comment: the `x1` and `y1` values are never used/incremented in the while loop

Comment: Format your code before posting in anywhere. Eclipse -> `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`, NetBeans -> `Alt`+`Shift`+`F`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
class PaintablePicture extends Picture {
    public PaintablePicture(String fileName) {
        super(fileName);
    }

    public void purpleSplotch(int x, int y) {
        int x1 = 0;
        int y1 = 1;
        while (x1 < x * 2)
            while (y1 < y * 3)

            {
                Color purple = new Color(175, 0, 175);
                Pixel pixRef;
                // get pixels (x1, y1) instead of (x, y) there is use to set the color of the same pixel(x,y) in a loop
                pixRef = this.getPixel(x1, y1);
                pixRef.setColor(purple);
                // increment y1
                y1++;

            }
        // increment x1
        x1++;
    }
}
```

In your while loop the looping variables `x1` and `y1` are never changed which means that they are always `0` and `1` which will satisfy the condition forever, that is why your program is running forever.

In any loop with a temp variable you need to change the value of the loop variable so that the condition will get satisfied at some stage.

Here we will increment the `x1` and `y1` variables inside their loop and the retuen statement in the `x1` loop will cause the loop to exit after the first execution, it has to be removed.

Also you were getting the pixels (x,y) always, values of x and y remains a constant through out the loop, I guess what you need here is pixles (x1, y1)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not incrementing the variables used as indexes in your `while` loops, so the loops runs indefinitely. Increment both variables (`x1` and `y1`) to ensure that you will exit both while loops at some point. Right now, `x1` will never exceed `x` and `y1` will never exceed `y`.

```
while(x1 < x*2) {
    while(y1 < y*3) {
         Color purple = new Color(175, 0, 175);
         Pixel pixRef;
         pixRef= this.getPixel(x,y);
         pixRef.setColor(purple);
         //increment y1 here
         y1++;
    }
    //increment x1 here
    x1++;
}
```

Comment: the color won't change to purple, it's not showing up on my picture,

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will run forever

```
while(x1 < x*2)
```

with x having a value bigger than 0 as in the call to the method

```
pRef.purpleSplotch(14,14);
```

Same happens with the while loop for y1.

You may need to increment x1 and y1 in purpleSplotch method. I don't know what it has to do but the conditions will always be true hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Hi I corrected it but now my splotches won't show up and I'm sad